# Fetch values into dropdown list column based on query from another list - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lookup-column, dropdown

Please help me with some code (preferrably jquery).
Sharepoint 2016.
I have List 1 with columns Resource, Attribute1, Attribute2,..., Attribute10. And I have another List 2 with columns Project, Resource, DefaultAttribute. Resource in List2 is a lookup of Resource in List1. 
I want DefaultAttribute to work as dropdown from the values of Attribute1, Attribute2,...,Attribute10 linked to the value of the appropriate Resource. Example: if value "Object5" is selected in the Resource field in List 2, then DefaultAttribute field should dropdown values from the values of Attribute1, Attribute2, ...,Attribute10 of row in List1 where Resource is "Object5".

I dont want to have DefaultAttribute auto-populated, but to enable user to select the value.

I am new to jquery, I can query list items, but I don' know how to fetch the data into the dropdown list column.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If possible can you add some screenshots for better understanding of your question?